# Count the number of elements in current-group xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am grouping elements by id and want to do something if there is more than one element with the same id (i. e. more than one element in the current group, right?)

I saw this here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/Usecountandcurrentgrouptocountgroups.htm

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
```

however, it always outputs 1, although I definitely have elements with the same id.

How do I count the number of elements in each group?

Comment: Are you using the XML and XSLT shown in that link, as the `count` should work in that case (See http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJu)? If you are using different XML and XSLT, could you please edit your question to show it? Thanks!

Comment: Your code has a bug in it. Show us your code, and we'll help you find it.